# Why will my JButton not update the imageicon?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

Currently I'm trying to make Video Poker. So far it consists of 2 classes:
Card with int value, char suit, and boolean checked. Card is a JButton. Then Deck with a stack of Card objects.

The JButton in the VideoPoker class just won't update the ImageIcon **when I draw a card**, and I can't figure out why for the life of me. It updates it when I want the background image and then again when I want the original image, so why not a new card?

below is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class VideoPoker extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private Deck deck;
    private Card[] cards;
    private JButton draw;
    private final int MAXCARDS = 5;

    public VideoPoker() {
        deck = new Deck();
        cards = new Card[MAXCARDS];
        for(int i = 0; i < MAXCARDS; i++) {
            cards[i] = deck.Draw();
            cards[i].addActionListener(this);
            add(cards[i]);
            cards[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon
                            ("Cards/" + cards[i].getValue() +
                            cards[i].getSuit() + ".png"));
        }
        draw = new JButton("Draw");
        draw.addActionListener(this);
        add(draw);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == draw) {
            int checked = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < MAXCARDS; i++) {
                if(cards[i].getChecked()) {
                    cards[i] = deck.Draw();
                    cards[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon
                            ("Cards/" + cards[i].getValue() + 
                            cards[i].getSuit() + ".png"));
                    checked++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(e.getSource() instanceof Card) {
            Card source = (Card)e.getSource();
            if(!source.getChecked()) {
                source.setChecked(true);
                source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Cards/back.png"));
            }
            else {
                source.setChecked(false);
                source.setIcon(new ImageIcon
                        ("Cards/" + source.getValue() +
                        source.getSuit() + ".png"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any error message, stacktrace or whatsoever?

Comment: No, nothing. Before I added the (e.getSource() instanceof Card), I was getting a ClassCastException. But that's irrelevent, I guess, so no.

Comment: Do you actually get at the place where the cards are being "reversed" again to show their original image?

Comment: By the time this game is distributed the images will most likely be an embedded-resource and thereafter must be accessed by `URL`, not `File`.

Comment: Yes. They will show their original image every time. I'll look into that, Andrew. Thanks.

Comment: To notify someone of a new comment, add @PersonName.  I suggest you look into it now *instead* of attempting to load the images by `File`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I am. I'm sorting through some code I found trying to figure out what exactly it means so I can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is caused by not adding the newly drawn card to the VideoPoker panel. When the draw event is handled, items in the cards array can be replaced, but these card/button objects are not yet added to the panel:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == draw) {
        int checked = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAXCARDS; i++) {
            if(cards[i].getChecked()) {
                cards[i] = deck.Draw();
                cards[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon
                        ("Cards/" + cards[i].getValue() + 
                        cards[i].getSuit() + ".png"));
                checked++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() instanceof Card) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When you remove the old card from the panel just before getting a new one and add the new card to the panel after that, the card changes on the screen as well.

```
                remove(cards[i]);
                cards[i] = deck.Draw();
                add(cards[i]);
```

There is still some work to do because the card needs to be added at the right position.

You can also change your design and use a CardButton that has a reference to a card instead of having a Card that is a button. That way you can have five fixed CardButtons and let these reference the right Card objects, making the buttons and cards less tightly coupled.

Comment: I could swear I tried that. Apparently not, though. Thanks! Maybe position sorting won't be too bad.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how exactly to break Card into 2 classes. I can see the reason behind doing so, but I don't understand what it would mean as far as implementation. CardButton extends Card? Or CardButton has a Card card and extends JButton? I think if I could break it into 2 classes I could eliminate the positioning issue. (Which I have an idea of how to solve, but I don't really want to go there.)

Comment: Broke it into 2 classes, found the solution. Thank you very much for the help.